# Least intensive way to style element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Just curious if anyone knows if adding a class to an element via `.classList.add()` is faster/less resource intensive than simply styling the element directly in javascript using `.style`?

Would it be even? Or is one faster than the other?

I imagine that `.style` would be better since the script doesn't have to talk to the CSS file. But maybe its only faster if you're styling one style. Plus removing the style if its for multiple things would be more script code.

tl;dr Which is better to use?

```
element.classList.add("displayclass");
```

```
.displayclass{
   display: none;
}
```

Vs.

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I am not sure which is faster. But as a designer/developer I much prefer scripts that use classes to add styling because its easier to work with and overwrite. Inline styles are more annoying to debug.

Comment: Ah yeah I can see that. I've just started learning web design this month and was curious if there's a general consensus on which is usually used.

Comment: In this example I would use element.style.display = "none" beacause there is only one property declared, and this is faster way than declaring whole class (3 lines of code vs 1 line of code). If your class had more properties declared apart from display property, then it would make sense to use element.classList.add("displayclass").

Answer (score 0):

I also think that using classes and styling in your css/sass/etc files is a way better approach than manually using the `style` attribute on an element.
I always feel the `style` attribute is/should be used/seen as like a "manual override"